# How do I use TypeScript 1.6 with Visual Studio Code to get generators support?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I've been targeting ES6 for a while in Visual Studio Code, but when I try to switch to TypeScript, it throws errors such as:

> Generators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6

But my **tsconfig.json** does have the ES6 target:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

So I tried `npm install -g typescript@1.6.0-beta` but it looks like VSCode doesn't care.

> Generators are not currently supported.

How can I get TypeScript and generators to work properly together in VS Code?

#### Update

Changing `typescript.tsdk` to the 1.6 binary seems to fix IntelliSense errors, but this **tasks.json** still prints out `error TS1220: Generators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher.`:

```
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
"showOutput": "silent",
"windows": {"command": "tsc.exe"},
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["app.ts"],
"problemMatcher": "$tsc"
```

However, `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --target ES6 app.ts` used manually in the terminal does work.

Comment: If you figure it out, please share! I'm also very much interrested

Comment: @bali182 done :) good luck!

Comment: Wow, thanks, looking at this, its probably worth waiting until its out of beta & production 1.6 is released :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know now!

## 1. IntelliSense

You can use the `typescript.tsdk` setting to point VSCode to TypeScript binaries. Upgrade your TypeScript to 1.6 and set the location properly.

You can do it either in your user/workspace settings, or per project in the **.vscode/settings.json** file. OS X example:

```
"typescript.tsdk": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"
```

## 2. Compiler

You also need to make sure your **.vscode/tasks.json** points to the new binary and makes the compiler operate in *Explicit project mode*, i.e. use tsconfig.json instead of taking a list of files to compile as an argument.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "windows": {"command": "tsc.exe"},
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [], //do not pass any files to the compiler. This way it will use tsconfig.json where you can set target: "ES6"
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

And finally **tsconfig.json** (in the project's root directory):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6", //The key, of course.
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode"
    ]
}
```

Restart the editor afterwards!

Comment: that's work in typescript 1.7-dev, in 1.6 it will failed to compile

Comment: In my case I needed to run the tsc compiler installed locally as an npm package. Here's `.vscode/tasks.json` that worked for me:

{
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "command": "${cwd}/node_modules/.bin/tsc",
 "isShellCommand": true,
 "showOutput": "silent",
 "args": [],
 "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}

Answer (score 0):

You can change your user settings in VS Code and set `"typescript.tsdk"` to a custom location .

If you install the nightly (`npm install -g typescript@next`), you can point to that version of TypeScript's `lib` folder.

## More

Reasons and setup instructions for using ts latest are covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html#typescript-version

Comment: Thanks for help. I actually tried this already and even posted as an answer, but deleted it because even though IntelliSense errors are gone, `CMD+Shift+B` still spews out `app.ts(112,20): error TS1220: Generators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 or higher.` despite pointing tasks.json to the same binary.

Comment: @basarat This is actually the lib folder now. The bin folder does not work.

Comment: @Schotime yup. Was a typo