# How to configure my VSCode to use older version of TypeScript(we use 1.6.3)?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Our team uses VS2015 for development and our typescript properties set the version of Typescript to use as 1.6.3.

I downloaded the 1.26.0 version of VSCode. But VSCode is by default using the typescript version to be 3.0.1.

I want to configure my VSCode to use typescript 1.6.3 so that my project would not have errors on build.

I followed the below instructions too. But it did not work for me.

[How do I use TypeScript 1.6 with Visual Studio Code to get generators support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380131/how-do-i-use-typescript-1-6-with-visual-studio-code-to-get-generators-support)

Any pointers would help.

Comment: How far did you get following the instructions you linked?  Do you have TypeScript 1.6.3 installed to the point that you can run `tsc --version` and it prints 1.6.3?  Did you set the `typescript.tsdk` setting?

Comment: Yes I did that. when I set the typescript.tsdk to the tsc of that version, VSCode complained that it is unable to find the tsserver and started using 3.0.0.

Comment: `typescript.tsdk` needs to be set to the directory that contains the `tsc.js` and `tsserver.js` files, not directly to the `tsc` executable.  Depending on your OS and how you installed `tsc`, this directory you need most likely has a path ending in `node_modules/typescript/lib` and is located somewhere near the `tsc` executable.

Comment: I got it now thanks.